# YouTube Data API Quota Issue

Tags: api, youtube, quota

Since Google Cloud charges you to get support from them theirselves, I decided to just write it here. Basically, I requested a quota increase for the YouTube Data API V3. After waiting I received my quota. However, youtube messed up and set the **Quota For Requests Per Minute** instead of setting the **Quota For Requests Per Day**. This means my requests/day quota is still the old one, which I need more of. 
Since I am unable to contact Google Cloud support directly because I am not able to purchase their paid support plan at this time, what do you guys think I should do?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I want to check that too